# BlazorBootstrap 5 columns: combine equal-width and set width

Tags: c#, blazor, multiple-columns, bootstrap-5

I tried the bootstrap 5 tutorial and have the following question regarding it's responsiveness:
As far as i understood,
rules apply from small to large (e.G. first sm, then md)
the first applied rule is the general rule without sizes (e.G. col-12)

Now i have to parts of information i wanna display next to each other on a big screen
and stacked vertically on small screens.
therefor i made a row with 2 columns,
each class has col-12 for small screens and col-md-6 for the bigger screen.

now i want to toogle the right part of information depending on a bollean (with a button changed),

so I wrote:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md" style="background-color:lightblue">
            this is always visible
        </div>
        @if (displaySecond)
        {
            <div class="col-12 col-md" style="background-color:lightcoral">
             optional optic
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <TelerikButton OnClick="@(() => displaySecond = !displaySecond)">Display</TelerikButton>
    </div>
</div>


@code{
    private bool displaySecond = false;
}
```

Where is the problem here?
expected behaviour:
On big screen: the first is in full width, if second is hidden
the first and the second are half with each, if both visible
On small screen:
each of both parts is in its own row.

Are there any suggestions?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to remove the col-12 and let the default behaviour take over.

The break point for Bootstrap col-mdxxx is 768px, so "col-md" only comes into effect for page widths greater then 768px.  Below that you get stacked divs, there's no col defined.

If you want more control you can see that in the code below where I set different md sizes for each column.

```
@page "/Test"
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md" style="background-color:lightblue">
            this is always visible
        </div>
        @if (displaySecond)
        {
            <div class="col-md" style="background-color:lightcoral">
                optional optic
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md @col1" style="background-color:lightblue">
            this is always visible
        </div>
        @if (displaySecond)
        {
            <div class="col-md @col2" style="background-color:lightcoral">
                optional optic
            </div>
        }

    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button @onclick="Display2">Display</button>
    </div>
</div>


@code{
    private bool displaySecond = false;

    private void Display2(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        displaySecond = !displaySecond;
    }

    private string col1 => displaySecond ? "col-md-4" : "";

    private string col2 => displaySecond ? "col-md-8" : "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I actually hoped, that i do not have to mix code and styling, because of seperation of concerns and maybe other patterns.
In this case I stil have to create css rules by logic/c#.
Then my view-logic does need to know about bootstrap and about how items are aligned.
Also it's hard to change the styles because i have to look up the string literals.

I just hoped there is another solution, which is only with simple bootstrap-css, (no if, no variables). As far as I see there is not. Thnak you very much for clearance.